# Bootstrap and equal horizontal menu title spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some menu links in equal width bootstrap `col-md-2` columns but the link text varies in length. How would I best evenly space the link text? Varying the column class between `col-md-1` and `col-md-3` would not give an accurate enough adjustment.

I've setup a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nickwuk/hr4fm4gf/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row rowtopmargin">
                    <div id="footpayments" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">Logo</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks col-md-offset-1"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks fl2"><a href="#">Data Sheets</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="#">Samples Policy</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="#">Terms</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="#">FAQ</a></div>
                            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block footermenuseperator"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks col-md-offset-1"><a href="#">Promise</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 footerlinks last"><a href="#">Case Studies</a></div>
                            <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block footermenuseperator"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end #footer -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end container fluid -->
</div>
```

Comment: "How would I best evenly space the link text?" - Do you want evenly spaced text relative to each other or relative to cell they are in?

Comment: If the text in row 1 and 2 were in an imaginary columns where the column widths were just as wide as the widest text in that column, then I would want the imaginary columns to be evenly spaced. So the imaginary column for Terms & Home would be the most narrow and the Samples Policy and Privacy Policy would be the widest, and the separation between those imaginary columns would be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using bootstrap and bootstrap classes already come with left and right padding therefore to adjust the link space I would suggest you to remove the right padding from col-md-2 class, before doing that assign it another class.

Comment: I think the first column with 'Contact' and 'Promise' would still be too wide even without the right padding, so maybe I should over-ride the col-md-2 class width with a new class which only applies at wider screen widths and is reset for mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to add a new class to each div that specified a new percentage width, in the css I added the following:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.w14pc {width:14.25%}
.w185pc {width:18.5%}
.w20pc {width:20.385%}
.w12pc {width:12.2%}
.w18pc {width:18%}
}
```